# jQuery .show() and .hide() problems with IE9 and FF15+

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several hidden DIVs on one page, each one of those contains an external flash player. In order to Hide/Show the DIVs I use this JS:

```
$('.showSingle').click(function(){

    $(".targetDiv").css("visibility","hidden");
    $(".targetDiv").hide("fast");

    $("#div"+$(this).attr('target')).css("visibility","visible");
    $('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show('fast');

});
```

The HTML is:

```
<div id="div'.$x.'" class="targetDiv" style="visibility: hidden">';

//Player code

</div>
```

Chrome, Opera, IE7 - all fine. Flash players are hidden, playing when set to visible, stop playing once hidden.

IE9 (works only if EmulateIE7 is set) - Flash players are hidden, playing when set to visible, though don't stop playing when set to hidden again.

FireFox. Everything works fine with FF12, though in FF15+ the DIVs are hidden but all of the flash players start playing once the page loads, this is regardless of then being hidden or visible.

Any solutions to fixing FF and IE9?

Answer (score 0):

If they are you're flash files and have ActionScript methods to pause them the best method would be to pause them via the javascript.

You can also try setting autoplay= false in the embed command.

But with control from the javascript it should be easy.

Here's an   [example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)  of how to access Flash via javascript

Comment: I probably should'v mentioned this, I do have autoplay = true and I do need to keep it that way. Some pages have as many as 100 flash players, click a button to show + to play + to pause + to show the second one, is quite a long list of clicks. With autoplay = true, all you do is click to show (auto play), click to show the second one (first one closes, auto pause, auto play on new one).

I don't have any further controls on the flash play, apart from size, autoplay and color.